# Using DECODE to state the category of table values

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

**Task**

Print all the employee numbers, name and salary. With the salary also print the category based on following criteria: LOW if salary is less than 900, MEDIUM if salary is less than 1500 and HIGH if greater than 1500.

**Attempted Query**

```
select ename ,sal , decode ( sign (sal - 900) , -1 , 'Low' ,
1 ,'Medium'   ) from emp;
```

My course teacher tell us using DECODE function write a query.

**Q )** How to achieve this by using decode function

Comment: School assignment? Show us table definitions, sample table data, the expected result - and also your current query attempt.

Comment: DECODE? It's a case for `case`...

Comment: I am using Sample Database of oracle (Emp, dept, salgrade )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT empno, ename, sal,
    CASE WHEN sal < 900 THEN 'LOW'
         WHEN sal < 1500 THEN 'MEDIUM'
         ELSE 'HIGH'
    END AS category
FROM emp
```

Answer (score 1):

By using DECODE function.

```
select ename ,sal , decode ( sign (round((sal - 900)/600 - 0.5 )) , -1 , 'Low' ,
1 ,'High' , 0 , 'Medium'  ) as "Salary Status"  from emp;
```